# Writing down these functions in a more sophisticated way

Tags: performance, actionscript-3

I'm creating a simple scratch game (6 cards). It doesn't even have to contain difficult logic. You eventually win all the time ;)

The code i wrote works pretty well, but i keep thinking it could be better. I'm not too familiar with coding, but i'm learning step by step.

Do you have ideas to write this down in a cleaner and more sophisticated way?

E.g. I tried to separate the IF statement that returns in every function, so i would only have to write it down once, but i didn't succeed.

Thanks in advance for looking.

```
//set card variables to 0 and when they're scratched, they're changed to 1
var checkCard1:int = 0, checkCard2:int = 0, checkCard3:int = 0, checkCard4:int = 0, checkCard5:int = 0, checkCard6:int = 0;

leaf1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked1);
function cardChecked1 (event:MouseEvent):void {
    checkCard1 = 1;
    if (checkCard1 && checkCard2 && checkCard3 && checkCard4 && checkCard5 && checkCard6  == 1) {

    var myDelay:Timer = new Timer(2000);
    myDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showMessage);
    myDelay.start();

    function showMessage(event:TimerEvent):void{
    myDelay.stop();
    gotoAndStop("nowinner");
    }
  }
}

leaf2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked2);
function cardChecked2 (event:MouseEvent):void {
    checkCard2 = 1;
    if (checkCard1 && checkCard2 && checkCard3 && checkCard4 && checkCard5 && checkCard6  == 1) {

    var myDelay:Timer = new Timer(2000);
    myDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showMessage);
    myDelay.start();

    function showMessage(event:TimerEvent):void{
    myDelay.stop();
    gotoAndStop("nowinner");
    }
  }
}

leaf3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked3);
function cardChecked3 (event:MouseEvent):void {
    checkCard3 = 1;
    if (checkCard1 && checkCard2 && checkCard3 && checkCard4 && checkCard5 && checkCard6  == 1) {

    var myDelay:Timer = new Timer(2000);
    myDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showMessage);
    myDelay.start();

    function showMessage(event:TimerEvent):void{
    myDelay.stop();
    gotoAndStop("nowinner");
    }
  }
}

leaf4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked4);
function cardChecked4 (event:MouseEvent):void {
    checkCard4 = 1;
    if (checkCard1 && checkCard2 && checkCard3 && checkCard4 && checkCard5 && checkCard6  == 1) {

    var myDelay:Timer = new Timer(2000);
    myDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showMessage);
    myDelay.start();

    function showMessage(event:TimerEvent):void{
    myDelay.stop();
    gotoAndStop("nowinner");
    }
  }
}

leaf5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked5);
function cardChecked5 (event:MouseEvent):void {
    checkCard5 = 1;
    if (checkCard1 && checkCard2 && checkCard3 && checkCard4 && checkCard5 && checkCard6  == 1) {

    var myDelay:Timer = new Timer(2000);
    myDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showMessage);
    myDelay.start();

    function showMessage(event:TimerEvent):void{
    myDelay.stop();
    gotoAndStop("nowinner");
    }
  }
}

leaf6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked6);
function cardChecked6 (event:MouseEvent):void {
    checkCard6 = 1;

    if (checkCard1 && checkCard2 && checkCard3 && checkCard4 && checkCard5 && checkCard6  == 1) {

    var myDelay:Timer = new Timer(2000);
    myDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showMessage);
    myDelay.start();

    function showMessage(event:TimerEvent):void{
    myDelay.stop();
    gotoAndStop("nowinner");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principles by moving redudant code into functions.  I also changed your check variables to be Booleans instead of ints.  If you are only using them for a checked/unchecked flag, then a Boolean is all you need.

```
var checkCard1:Boolean = false, checkCard2:Boolean = false, checkCard3:Boolean = false, checkCard4:Boolean = false, checkCard5:Boolean = false, checkCard6:Boolean = false;

function checkAllCards()
{
    if (checkCard1 && checkCard2 && checkCard3 && checkCard4 && checkCard5 && checkCard6)
    {
        var myDelay:Timer = new Timer(2000);
        myDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showMessage);
        myDelay.start();

        function showMessage(event:TimerEvent):void{
            myDelay.stop();
            gotoAndStop("nowinner");
        }
    }
}

function cardChecked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (event.currentTarget === leaf1)
    { checkCard1 = true; }
    else if (event.currentTarget === leaf2)
    { checkCard2 = true; }
    else if (event.currentTarget === leaf3)
    { checkCard3 = true; }
    else if (event.currentTarget === leaf4)
    { checkCard4 = true; }
    else if (event.currentTarget === leaf5)
    { checkCard5 = true; }
    else if (event.currentTarget === leaf6)
    { checkCard6 = true; }
    checkAllCards();
}

leaf1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked);
leaf2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked);
leaf3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked);
leaf4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked);
leaf5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked);
leaf6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, cardChecked);
```

I didn't write a tester app for this, so let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: thanks that's some good advice. i'm going to try this now. 
will be back to let you know how it works out :)

Comment: It's running without a problem :) You've given me the info/inspiration to rewrite some more now. Thanks again.

Comment: I prefer early outs over large if statements - it makes the code quicker and so much easier to read. Change the `checkAllCards()` if to: `if ( !checkCard1 || !checkCard2 || !checkCard3 || !checkCard4 || !checkCard5 || !checkCard6) return;` - if it passes that, you know you're good

Comment: It's preference; I personally prefer the && technique.  Regardless, both will compile and run as intended. Speed difference would be negligible at best; Use whichever style you like!